# Autofac: Where is AutofacContrib.Monitoring?

Tags: autofac

From this [page](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ImprovingPerformance):

*...This can yield an improvement of up to 10x faster Resolve() calls, but only makes sense for components that appear in many object graphs. Get activation counts using **AutofacContrib.Monitoring** to determine which components are worth switching.*

Where is the "AutofacContrib.Monitoring"? I downloaded *AutofacContrib-2.4.4.705-NET40.zip* from the official download page, and also searched in the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/) and Google, but couldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutofacContrib.Monitoring has never been released, it is in the source repository only.

A better option is to get Whitebox from http://whitebox.googlecode.com (you'll need to build from source but it is worth the effort :))

Nick